# How to delete where user taps

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, setstate

I'm trying to make my app delete where the user taps, but it deletes the last list item instead.
This part is where I want to delete. On the onTap function. I have it set to remove at the index which I thought should be the int created by the item builder.

```dart
void _showPopupMenu(Offset offset, index) async {
  double left = offset.dx;
  double top = offset.dy;
  await showMenu(
    context: context,
    position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, 10000, 0),
    items: [
      PopupMenuItem(
      value: 'Delete',
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text('Delete'),
        onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              checkBoxesCheckedStates.remove(index);
            });
        }
        ),
      ),
    ],
    elevation: 4.0,
  );
}
```

This next bit is where the contents of the list gets created. I have a feeling that instead of List bool I might have to change it to int, but I'm not 100% sure.

```dart
List<bool> checkBoxesCheckedStates = [false];
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: checkBoxesCheckedStates.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return CheckboxListTile(
                  title: TextField(
                      autocorrect: true,
                    ),
                  value: checkBoxesCheckedStates[index],
                  secondary: GestureDetector(onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details){
                    _showPopupMenu(details.globalPosition, checkBoxesCheckedStates[index]);
                  },child: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                  onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      checkBoxesCheckedStates[index] = newValue;
                    });
                  },);
            },
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                checkBoxesCheckedStates.add(false);
              });
            },
            ),
        )
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You need `TextEditingController` `List` to control `TextField` and use `removeAt`

```
List<TextEditingController> controllerList = [TextEditingController()];

onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  checkBoxesCheckedStates.removeAt(index);
                  controllerList.removeAt(index);
                });
                
onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                checkBoxesCheckedStates.add(false);
                controllerList.add(TextEditingController());
              });
            },
```

Step 2: `_showPopupMenu(details.globalPosition, index);` just pass `index` 
Step 3:  `Navigator.pop(context);` to dismiss `Delete`

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List<bool> checkBoxesCheckedStates = [false];
  List<TextEditingController> controllerList = [TextEditingController()];

  void _showPopupMenu(Offset offset, index) async {
    print(index);
    double left = offset.dx;
    double top = offset.dy;
    await showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, 10000, 0),
      items: [
        PopupMenuItem(
          value: 'Delete',
          child: ListTile(
              title: Text('Delete'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  checkBoxesCheckedStates.removeAt(index);
                  controllerList.removeAt(index);
                });
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ),
      ],
      elevation: 4.0,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: checkBoxesCheckedStates.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return CheckboxListTile(
                title: TextField(
                  controller: controllerList[index],
                  autocorrect: true,
                ),
                value: checkBoxesCheckedStates[index],
                secondary: GestureDetector(
                    onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                      _showPopupMenu(details.globalPosition, index);
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    checkBoxesCheckedStates[index] = newValue;
                  });
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                checkBoxesCheckedStates.add(false);
                controllerList.add(TextEditingController());
              });
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Test(),
    );
  }
}
```